# Load img src tag instead of css background

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an existing project I have found and improved,I'm trying to modify it again, so Ill be able to add dynamically custom images, Here is the new project I did:
[Logo Bubbles](https://codepen.io/eran-levi/pen/vYJQMMo)

Now, Instead of using one big image, and loading the relevant part, I need to dynamically create new "image bubbles" from any image src URL.

I tried changing this project to replace the bubbles with images dynamically, but I could only load the first image on the list:
[Custom Images Bubbles](https://codepen.io/eran-levi/pen/XWaywWB)

```
this.el = document.createElement("img");
    this.el.src = src;
    bubblesEl.appendChild(this.el);
```

Can you please assist? what is missing in order to create image bubbles (same as we have on the first link) dynamically, in a random position?

Appreciate your help, Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Eran your code is not complete. Please try the recommended minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you want to load the logos image in the form of ```bubbles``` in your example? my code only load the image of the *man* and *woman*.

Comment: @h.devillefletcher -> No, I need to call a function and load an image from URL, and that will create the bubble, so If Ill call the function with 1 URL, Ill see a bubble with the image, then after a second, Ill read it again with URL2, Ill see another bubble with URL2.

Comment: Did you have tried creating a new ```bubbleSpecs``` and set it's as ```bubbleSpecsNew = [{ s: 0.6, x: 500, y: 45 }]```, this makes appear 2 bubbles if you call as ```new Bubbles(bubbleSpecsNew, "https://i.imgur.com/T4EpAg6.png");```.